# Google Feed Loader API ignoring XML attributes

Tags: jquery, xml, json, rss, google-feed-api

Google's feed loader appears to be ignoring attributes when converting to JSON. 
I'm using jQuery to grab a feed via AJAX.
The actual RSS XML feed can be seen [here](http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=ALevCVux), and the response from the AJAX call can be seen [here](http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=MLzQYb8M).

I need to access the `url`attribute of the `<enclosure>` tags, but neither appear in the response.

For reference, the code I am using is:

```
function getFeed(url) {
    url = 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/feed/load?v=1.0&num=10&callback=?&q=' 
            + encodeURIComponent(url);
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: url,
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        cache: false,
        success: function(d) { alert(JSON.stringify(d); },
        error: function(s,x) { alert(x); }
    }); 
}
```

I can't figure out how to get an XML response instead, as changing `dataType : 'xml'` causes an HTTP error. JSON is preferable.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The 'enclosure' tag is not included in the JSON response, so you have two options setting the output argument:

You need to set the output to 'XML': https://developers.google.com/feed/v1/jsondevguide#json_args

```
url = 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/feed/load?v=1.0&output=xml&num=10&callback=?&q='+ encodeURIComponent(url);
```

Or use the mixed format: https://developers.google.com/feed/v1/devguide#resultMixed

```
url = 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/feed/load?v=1.0&output=json_xml&num=10&callback=?&q='+ encodeURIComponent(url);
```

You´ll get the JSON plus a a new xmlString property with all the tags (including 'enclosure' attributes)

```
alert(d.responseData.xmlString);
```

In both cases you need to parse the XML string and navigate to the needed info

Hope this helps

Comment: Thank you so much. I didn't know you could get a Mixed format response without including the Google API. I haven't tried it yet, but this is the answer I was looking for. :)

Comment: Just let us know when you try if it worked and paste some code of how do you solved it.

Comment: I used the mixed format, retrieved the string, appended it to a hidden element so IE doesn't choke, and navigated through it using jQuery. `$('#hiddenDiv').append(data.responseData.xmlString); $('#hiddenDiv').get(0).getElementsByTagName('enclosure')[i].getAttribute('url')`

Comment: wow this is the only post on all of stackoverflow that shows the flexibility of adjusting the google api ajax feed service, to receive custom element fields. amazing!

Comment: FYI this helped me to "eval" contents from xmlstring:

`$("#hidden").append(entries.xmlString);
$("#hidden").html($("#hidden").find("description").text());`

Comment: This here returns the string contents of the `description` element in the xmlString:

`$($(entries.xmlString)[2]).find("description").text();`