# How to get MIXED FORMAT with google feed API using AngularJS

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, feed

Im using the google's feed API with AngularJS and I need to get my feed data in a mixed format (json & xml). I'm using the following code to call the Google's Api throught ngResurce, I'd been trying change the method  and callback tags to MIXED_FORMAT but I couldn't make it works. Here Google explains how to use it, but I have no idea about how to apply it to AngularJS https://developers.google.com/feed/v1/devguide#resultMixed

```
.factory('FeedLoader', function ($resource) {
    return $resource('http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/feed/load', {}, {
        fetch: { method: 'JSONP', params: {v: '1.0', callback: 'JSON_CALLBACK'} }
    });
})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply add it to the params in your query. I modified your example to set the output format to mixed mode.

```
.factory('FeedLoader', function ($resource) {
    return $resource('http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/feed/load', {}, {
        fetch: { method: 'JSONP', params: {v: '1.0', callback: 'JSON_CALLBACK', output: 'json_xml'} }
    });
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I need parse the enclosure tag in order to get the url image. It's assumed I should get the MIXED OUTPUT with the json+xml code but I get a undefined value from the enclousure tag when I try parse it. I'm doing this like I saw at this post [Google Feed Loader API ignoring XML attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11139065/google-feed-loader-api-ignoring-xml-attributes) .In addition I tried to get the MIXED format writing the url manually but It doesn't work. There is my whole code. How could I know that Im getting the mixed json output?

```
var feeds = [];
var entryImageUrl = [];

angular.module('starter.controllers', ['ngResource','ngLocale'])

.factory('FeedLoader', function ($resource) {
        return $resource('http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/feed/load', {}, {
            fetch: { method: 'JSONP', params: {v: '1.0', callback: 'JSON_CALLBACK', output: 'json_xml'} }
        });
})

.service('FeedList', function ($rootScope, FeedLoader) {
    this.get = function() {
        var feedSources = [
            {title: 'Heraldo De Barbate', url: 'http://www.heraldodebarbate.es/rss/last'},
        ];
        if (feeds.length === 0) {
            for (var i=0; i<feedSources.length; i++) {
                FeedLoader.fetch({q: feedSources[i].url, num: 10}, {}, function (data) {
                    var feed = data.responseData.feed;
                    **var entryImageUrl = feed.xmlNode.getElementsByTagName("enclosure")[i].getAttribute("url");**
                    feeds.push(feed);
                });
            }
        }
        return feeds;
    };
})

.controller('FeedCtrl', function ($scope, FeedList,$timeout) {

  $scope.update = function(){
    $scope.feeds = FeedList.get();
    $scope.$on('FeedList', function (event, data) {
        $scope.feeds = data;
        // $scope.entryImageUrl 
        console.log(feeds);
    });
    $timeout(function() {
      $scope.$broadcast('scroll.refreshComplete');
    }, 500);    
  }
})
```